# Would towing icebergs to drought stricken countries be feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, water, ships, ice

It seems a simple solution to the world's water problems if it were feasible. What Would be entailed for such a monumental task, if say, the iceberg was 100 tons, and traveling from Greenland to the coast of California. What percentage of the ice would survive the trip ?

Comment: I've seen a discussion before. Looking at thermal transfer at the surface and the sunlight total, it takes a year or two to melt.  How long would it take to move? How much fuel (compared to desalination)?

Comment: Welcome to the site Fey.  I think a little more information is in order.  Specifically I would include the volume of the iceberg in question, the origin of the iceberg and its destination.  With that information we can actually calculate the cost to move it versus the energy cost of say a desalination plant.

Comment: Check out the [help] for more info on the site and feel free to join us in [chat]

Comment: I removed [tag:science] and replaced it with [tag:reality-check].  That seems more like what you want.  Other possibilities include [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science].

Comment: Hello Fey, welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. This is a site for the building of **fictional** worlds, mostly for the use in games, stories, or novels. Your question sounds as if you are suggesting a real-world solution to **real-world problems**, and I'm afraid that's not what we do here.

Comment: @o.m. just because it can be done in the real world doesn't mean it can't be part of someone's world they are creating.  This is something we do not currently do in the real world and could have an effect on the setting the author is creating.  Earth is a perfectly acceptable setting for us to discuss.

Comment: @James, I'm not saying that towing icebergs can't be discussed here. But this specific question doesn't *sound* like creating world.

Comment: @o.m. that's a judgement call on your part though and does not take into account the thought of the asker which is what matters...I suppose asking for clarification via comments is probably the best route...but asking about the feasibility of something we don't already do in the real world seems perfectly on topic to me.

Comment: @James, such things are always judgemental. As of now there are five close votes and one reopen vote, so my opinion doesn't seem to be unique.

Comment: @o.m. there is a difference between off-topic and *unclear what your are asking* which is why this was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water is cheap fuel is not.

The expensive part of providing fresh water is not the water but the fuel to move it where it is needed.

If I took a large tanker ship and filled it with freshwater I could move the same water at a much lower price.
Partly this is because the ship is much more hydrodynamic then a large irregular iceberg.  Also you will spend lots of energy moving ice that then melts and never reaches the destination.

A desalination plant might be even more efficient though I don't know.